# KVM Networking Topology

Tags: networking, kvm, bridge, jenkins

I would like to set up a network on my Server where I run KVM as a hypervisor.
The Network will be used for a distributed Jenkins setup.

The goal topology is the following:

- One machine (Jenkins master) should be accessible from the local network and have internet access.
- All other machines (Jenkins slave) should only be able to communicate with each other and the above mentioned machine.

I had the idea to do it the following way:

- Bridged network for the master.
- Isolated network for the slaves.

Then I thought I could try to give the slaves access to the master by configuring a gateway to the master's subnet and vice versa.

Now I don't know if this is the way to go. How I can provide such a gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to use [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/) where you can have a much wide range of configuration and management.

Second, answering your question, you can create a bridge (let's call *br0*) and add only the *Jenkins master VM*, then you create a second bridge (let's call *br1*) and add all the VMs, but not a physical interface (*eth0* for example). Finally as you mention, use *Jenkins master VM* as gateway and maybe firewall.

PS: this procedure is a little long, so let me know if I was vague and you didn't understand fully.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
How can I add the gateway? Should I just add a static route definition from the br0 network to br1 and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, just write a small script for routing and masquerading all the connections in the *Jenkins master VM*.